# Make a dynamic chromatic circle with hsl and javascript using for loop and map function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, hsl

What I want to achieve

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/9d7a842b93268568b5befcbdc579c7cd.png]

However in this code, a[0] will start with red (not violet). (at 12 oclock) Borders are not necessary.
I get to loop the colors in the code randomly or have all hsl colors of the same color, but unable to increase the hue part of the hsl in orderly fashion, let me explain:

array is generated on this function:

```
var firstcolor = 1;
  var endcolor = 360;
  const itemslength = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a').length;
  const sortearcolores = Math.trunc(360 / itemslength);
  var arr = [];
  for (var i3 = firstcolor; i3 < endcolor+1;  i3 += sortearcolores) {
    arr.push(i3)
  }

  console.log(arr)
```

and throw this on the console: `[1, 46, 91, 136, 181, 226, 271, 316]` which is **correct**!

But when I map through them I generate a new array that is equal to one above, in each item:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');
      for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        arr.map((value, index) => {
          items[i].style.backgroundColor = `hsla(${ value },91%,65%,1)`;
          console.log(value)
        }
      )}
```

So the problem clearly erradicates in this loop and don't know if I am using the wrong function.

HTML

```
<nav class="circular-menu">
       <div class="circle">
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
        <a href="" class="sub-circle"></a>
      </div>


  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x">+</a>
</nav>
```

Full Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){ 
//NON IMPORTANT FOR THE ISSUE
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

}

items = (function(arr){
  var firstcolor = 1;
  var endcolor = 360;
  const itemslength = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a').length;
  const sortearcolores = Math.trunc(360 / itemslength);
  var arr = [];
  for (var i3 = firstcolor; i3 < endcolor+1;  i3 += sortearcolores) {
    arr.push(i3)
  }

  console.log(arr)

  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');
  for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    arr.map((value, index) => {
      items[i].style.backgroundColor = `hsla(${ value },91%,65%,1)`;
      console.log(value)
    }
  )}
})

items()

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
};
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sanchocreativo/pen/XWWrvRR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Map function was not necessary, so I looped throught the items for the arr[i] in a for loop.

```
window.onload = function(){ 

  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

  for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

    items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  }

  items = (function(arr){
    var firstcolor = 1;
    var endcolor = 360;
    const itemslength = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a').length;
    const sortearcolores = Math.trunc(360 / itemslength);
    var arr = [];
    for (var i3 = firstcolor; i3 < endcolor+1;  i3 += sortearcolores) {
      arr.push(i3)
    }

    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');
    for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
          items[i].style.backgroundColor = `hsla(${ arr[i]},91%,65%,1)`;
    }
  })

  items()

  document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
  }
  };
```